# How do I use a different Spring datasource depending on the name of the unit test?

Tags: spring, datasource

)

I have a rather unusual requirement for a series of unit tests I'm fixing. Basically, a different datasource/transaction manager needs to be used depending on the method name of the unit test.

For example, if the test name ends with UseDB2, then we use the DB2 data source, if it's UseH2 then we use the H2 datasource.

I thought the way to go about this was to use the `AbstractRoutingDatasource` provided by the Spring framework.

```
public class TestRoutingDatasSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {

        return DatabaseContextHolder.getDatabaseType();

    }
}
```

Using a context holder to select the required datasource:

```
public class DatabaseContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<DType> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<DType>();

    public static void setDatabaseType(DType databaseType) {
        contextHolder.set(databaseType);
    }

    public static DType getDatabaseType() {
        return (DType) contextHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clearDatabaseType() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }
}
```

I was then going to use the name of the test to set the context; something like this:

```
public class MyDBUnitTestCase extends
        AbstractTransactionalDataSourceSpringContextTests {

    protected DataSource dataSource;

    protected String schemaName;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource aDataSource) {
        this.dataSource = aDataSource;
    }

    public void setSchemaName(String aSchemaName) {
        this.schemaName = aSchemaName;
    }

    protected void onSetUp() throws Exception {
        super.onSetUp();


        if (getName().endsWith("UsingDB2")) {

            DatabaseContextHolder.setDatabaseType(DType.DB2);
        }
        else {
            DatabaseContextHolder.setDatabaseType(DType.H2);
        }

    }
```

But of course, this won't work because by the time I've come to check the name of the test, Spring has already configured all the beans (doh!).

Is there some other mechanism I can use to get this to work?

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: What is the problem of splitting into two different test classes - one for DB2, another for H2?

Comment: Hi. Yes, I was trying to avoid moving things about too much as it's a very old code base that I'm trying not to mess around with too much, and if possible, I'd like to be able to switch to a different database by just changing the name of the test and rerunning. Still, that certainly an option (and a much easier one).

Comment: Can you use profiles to do this? check this out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-testing-separate-data-source

Comment: Yes, I think I'm really overcomplicating this. I think a variation of yegodm's answer is the best call: rearrange the tests and those that need the DB2 connection can be subclassed to use the correct connection.